# Meteor Collection undefined

Tags: collections, meteor

everyone.
when I use a collection varibale in server folder, it makes a error."ReferenceError: Test is not defined"

here is the file struct:
collections
  --Test.coffee   #@Test = new Meteor.Collection "test"
server
  --mock_data
    --test_server.coffee #console.log Test.find().count()

but if i use collection "test" directly in server fodler, it works.
eg:
server
  --test_server.coffee #console.log Test.find().count()

I think the file loading rule of Meteor should be responsible for this problem. But I still
don't know why the problem occurred.

Answer (score 3):

I moved my collections.js to /lib and it solved my problem. Maybe it'll help you out, too?

Files in the /lib folder are executed before other files. Therefore ensuring that your collection "Test" is defined before any server script is loaded and ran.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that the "deeper" a folder is, the earlier it will be read. So test_server.coffee will be read before Test.coffee because it's nested deeper.

Here's some more info on how to structure your app:

https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq#where-should-i-put-my-files
http://docs.meteor.com/#structuringyourapp

Comment: thx,I also think my problem is about my file structure. And the file struction is important to the loading sequence.Thx again.